# How to change the Downloaded InfoPath form to Design Mode from SharePoint Site?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am new to InfoPath form development.
I have a sharepoint content type InfoPath form with default view set to EDIT Mode it has also more two modes that is DESIGN Mode & NEW for entering new Data in sharepoint site.

I have opened Template in InfoPath directly from Sharepoint Server now its default mode is EDIT but i now also need the DESIGN mode of this Template and the NEW Form Entry mode too. I dont know whether these all three modes are in one single template or they have different files.

Plz help me to get the Design mode and NEW mode of this EDIT mode form.

Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

When you use *InfoPath* for adding, displaying and editing list items, you will have a single template (`template.xsn`).

The differences between the browser views you have for displaying, adding and editing mode are caused by the fact that 3 different `.aspx` forms are being used for this: *displayifs.aspx*, *newifs.aspx* and *editifs.aspx*.

Each of these forms contains a [`BrowserFormWebPart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee564313%28v=office.14%29.aspx), whose `ListFormMode` attribute has specific values for each form: `ListFormMode="Editable"` for adding and editing and `ListFormMode="ReadOnly"` for displaying. When editing, the form is populated with values based on the query string parameter `ID`, which is the id of the edited item.

If this is your goal, a very convenient way of customizing the web part is to create separate views in *InfoPath* (for example a `MyCustomDisplay` for displaying the item) and then assign the view name to the web part in the *displayifs.aspx* web form (by using *SharePoint Designer*):

```
<WpNs0:BrowserFormWebPart DefaultView="MyCustomDisplay" runat="server" ... />
```

When an item will be displayed, `MyCustomDisplay` view will be used, but when an item will be edited or added, the default `Edit` view will be used.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for replying how should i open this in Design Form?

Comment: First of all, could you give more details about what you want to achieve? Do you want to customize the content?

Comment: Yes! I want to add the tab control for 'Design Mode' & 'New' mode now i have added in Edit Mode but not able to get the design mode of this form. how to get design & new Mode of this form

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know whether these all three modes are in one single template
>   or they have different files

It is in one template though the devil is in details and that you use incompatible terms interchangeable or in impossible/senseless context.

> I have opened Template in InfoPath directly from Sharepoint Server now
>   its default mode is EDIT but i now also need the DESIGN mode of this
>   Template and the NEW Form Entry mode too

There is no point to open Infopath template directly on Sharepoint server. In order to make changes and make the changed template available on Sharepoint server, you have to save it on local machine (it can be still the same machine as server but also client remote one), make changes and publish to Sharepoint in Infopath Designer.
It is template that is opened in **design mode** and in Infopath Designer.

The XML file data Infopath form file is created on the basis of the published XSN Infopath form template and it is linked to that template. It is that form that is opened (and using the XSN template, it is linked to) in **edit**, **new** or **display mode**. It is opened either in client Infopath filler or web browser (depending on the type of Infopath form and configuration, as well as availability of of the PFS - Infopath Form Services. The latter is available only on enterprise Sharepoint server).

> I dont know whether these all three modes are in one single template
>   or they have different files

It is on the same template. If the published to Sharepoint server Infopath form template is used as Infopath form Web Part in a custom Web part ASPX web page, then theoretically its mode should be configured through web part properties. Though, webpart propertis avail only edit mode, see my question and discussion in msdn forum:

- [How to change the type of infopath form received through "Get Form From" connection of web parts?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-IE/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/6f6530c8-6dc8-486f-9815-e4faa00d0163)

If you created Sharepoint List Form type of Infopath form template from a sharepoint list then the same published XSN Infopath form template is used [in the form of Infopath web part for different ASPX pages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/edit-list-forms-using-infopath-2010-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631624.aspx) :

- **editifs.aspx** in place of default Sharepoint **EditForm.aspx**  (for editing)
- **newifs.aspx** in place of default Sharepoint  NewForm.aspx (for creating/new)
- **DisplayIFS.aspx** in place of default Sharepoint **DispForm.aspx** (for displaying or viewing)

Here is my answer how to use combinations from all six webpages in parallel:

- [Using Default List Forms for Edit & View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43816)

  - [How to make Infopath Designer 2010 respect the default selected types (New, Edit, Display) for list forms?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/6af397b4-466f-4619-aba1-517f6367bd2c/)

Though, I wrote above sharepoint lists in order to illustrate that the same XSN template (and corresponding web part from it) is sued in different webpages.

But, the problem is that I do not see how "conent type" can be used with sharepoint lists. Only with form or document libraries. But what you describe does not fit with library forms either....